# Can two divs have the same background image (same file reference)?

Tags: css, background-image

**Warning - beginner's question!**

This is a simple question. I'm trying to google it but I see only search results where people ask whether it's possible to assign two background images to one div (question reversed).

When trying to set the background property of a div to the same file as another one (copying the property & value), the second div has no background image.

I get a warning in my dev tools and the new div's background image has no thumbnail when hovering in the Chrome dev tools.

This made me think that I can't set the background value of two distinct divs to the same image file.

I thought I could be efficient by re-using the file as background in different divs?!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible use the same image to different divs:

**Examples:**

With the following HTML:

```
<div id='one' class='test'></div>
<div id='two' class='test'></div>
```

You can achieve your task using Javascipt:

**Example 1  http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/wndcuq1j/**

```
var one = document.getElementById('one');
var two = document.getElementById('two');

var src = 'http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2012/163/0/d/dog_with_glasses_by_danihee-d53949b.jpg';

one.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+src+')';
two.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+src+')';
```

or else just with CSS:

**Example 2  http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/Lvu71sua/**

```
.test{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-size:100px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url('http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2012/163/0/d/dog_with_glasses_by_danihee-d53949b.jpg');
}
```

the image will be cached by browser, so the user will download them only the first time

Comment: It just up to you, you can do it also only with css, depend by your needs

Comment: @NilsSens I suggest you to use only CSS(example 2)